# {()=> (this.whatever)} vs {this.whatever}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

suppose we have a handler (inside our class extends component in react)

```
whatever = () => {
//Something 
}
```

when we do

`onClick="{()=> this.whatever}"` , as javascript process our code (or compile/read) this won't be executed until the click event happens

In contrast

{this.whatever} should be executed as soon as javascript reaches this point or reads this.

Hence, we generally use this `{()=> this.whatever}`  we want event to happen after someone say click? and `{this.whatever}` will execute handler/method immediately when JS compile?

**[Update]**

In a react application I was making by following some tutorial, we have arrow function handler say `whatever` which pass to child component like this `<BuildControls whatever={this.whatever} />` . Here in child component we do `<button onClick={props.whatever} />` which works. So why didn't we do `<button onClick={() => props.whatever} />` (also the onClick event doesn't work if we follow later approach)

Comment: `() => this.whatever()` and `this.whatever` will have the same effect in this case, since you create a property initialized arrow function. If you had made a regular class method `whatever() {}` on your class instead, you would have this problem: `var obj = { val: 1, fun: function() { return this.val; }}; var fun = obj.fun; obj.fun(); fun();`

Comment: You need to explicitly invoke functions in javascript, so `onClick={this.whatever}` will just assign the function to an event listener (React does this internally). `this.whatever` is just a reference to the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{this.whatever}` is not same with `{this.whatever()}`

In javascript (and most of other languages) to execute a function you need parenthesizes. If you use `{this.whatever}` you pass down a function as a parameter to a prop and when user clicks the passed function will be fired.

Below is the sample code showing difference.

```js
const whatever = () => {
  return "I log from function";
}

console.log(whatever); // returns function
console.log((() => whatever)); //returns a function that returns a function
console.log(whatever()); // runs the function
```

**Sample React App** ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnkq4lo55y))

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class CustomButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("passed function", this.props.onButtonClick);
    return (
      <button
        onClick={e => this.props.onButtonClick(e, "something from button")}
      >
        {this.props.name}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.test1 = this.test1.bind();
  }
  test1(e) {
    // I'm a regular function
    // I need to be bind
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test 1");
  }
  test2(e) {
    // I'm a regular function
    // I need to be bind
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test 2");
  }
  test3 = e => {
    // I'm an arrow function
    // I don't loose context of this
    // so I don't need to be bind
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test 3");
  };
  test4 = (e, text) => {
    // I am passed down to child component
    // run with an extra argument
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(text);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.test1}>Test 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.test2.bind(this)}>Test 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.test3}>Test 3</button>
        <CustomButton onButtonClick={this.test4} name="Test 4" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Some Documentation to read**

- [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Bennygenel thanks for amazing answer! `{this.whatever}` passes down a function. so when I do something like `onClick={this.whatever}` does this execute/call my function on click? or before click? If yes then `onClick={() => this.whatever}` also executes the function on click? (1/2)

Comment: In a react application I was making by following some tutorial, we have arrow  function handler say `purchasingHandlerOpen` which pass to child component like this  `purchasingHandlerOpen={this.purchasingHandlerOpen}` . Here in child component we do  `<button onClick={props.purchasingHandlerOpen} />` which works. So here why didn't we do `<button onClick={() => props.purchasingHandlerOpen} />` (also the onClick event doesn't work if we follow later approach)

Comment: @KuchBhi `onClick` is a native prop that runs the passed function with an event argument right after user clicks. With this information you need to pass a function. Arrow function is not necessary in this case because it just adds a second empty function to the function. I'll update my example.

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask, Can you update your example with the use of 'this' keyword?

Comment: @KuchBhi added a sample react app and some documentation link.

Answer (score 2):

```
{this.whatever}
```

is fine as long as the function it calls looks like

```
whatever = () => {
  //Something 
}
```

`{this.whatever()}` would get called immediately.

Its better to write a separate ES6 function so it doesn't cause the function to be rewritten everytime the page is re-rendered.

Comment: You are missing the use of `bind`

Comment: @J.Pichardo You don't need bind with es6, it does it on its own

Comment: That is for arrow functions only

Comment: @J.Pichardo that is true but it is an arrow function

Answer (score 1):

Both commands mean the same thing.

But `onClick={() => this.whatever()}` consumes more resources because every `render` call reinstantiates that function.

You want to use the arrow function whenever you need to consume the argument

```
onClick={event => this.whatever(event)}
```

Comment: if I do something like `whatever = (event) => {
//Something 
}` and then `onClick={this.whatever(event)}` . will that be equivalent to `onClick={event => this.whatever(event)}`

Comment: No, whenever you put the parenthesis after a function you're running it, `onClick` will become the `return` value of `whatever`